ruby bundle - no config files
I've been attempting to try ruby on rails.

I installed ruby: sudo apt-get install ruby-full

this gave me ruby 2.7.something


the rails intro says I need ruby 3.? so I deleted ruby:

sudo apt uninstall ruby-full, I think
this removed ruby-full but ruby 2.7.? remained
I rm'd ruby


sudo snap install ruby --classic

ruby 3.? installed but at a completely different location



I have installed rails and got it running however I am unable to work with gems if I need to install another gem.
I have tried installing menu_maker but it isn't found when I try and use it.
gem commands do not find menu_maker (an example gem, not a problem with menu_maker!)
I can see that menu_maker exists at ~/.gem/gems
bundle config shows nothing. I do not have a config file, neither at <project>/.bundle/config nor at ~/.bundle/config
I don't seem to have environment variables GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH set either.
I assume there's quite a bit gone wrong here. My question is how to get the configuration set up, that's the environment variables and the config file? And anything else you can see will be needed!
I did delete stuff when removing ruby 2.7.? but I installed ruby 3.? after that.
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Do not use apt-get to install Ruby - it will only give you greif.  Instead install a Ruby version manager like rbenv, rvm or asdf and use it to install rubies. This lets you have different Ruby versions for different projects and will ensure that the right gems are placed on your path. If you're installing Ruby with sudo all the gems also often end up with messed up file priviledges (as well as the security issues).

The same goes for Snap and other system wide package managers.

better to use rvm

Don't use apt to install ruby, because it installs system-wide which makes gem management difficult. Try using something like rvm, it will work a lot better.
